# Custom 404 page not being shown "File not found" shown instead

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I've got a website running on Apache 2.4 with PHP 8.0. In my .htaccess file I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Remove .php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If I try to access /test.html (a file that doesn't exist), it shows the 404 page, but if I try to access /test it shows "File not found." instead, and in the error log it says "Primary script unknown". Is there any way for it to display the 404 page instead?

Comment: Whenever you set up a routing system that is based on rewriting requests for not physically existing files to your script - then it becomes your script's responsibility to determine what content actually exists, and what needs to get a 404 response, _from_ your script. You can't rely on ErrorDocument 404 any more, because from the web server's point of view, this is _not_ a 404 any more - after all, the request got _successfully_ rewritten to your script.

Comment: @CBroe so would I need to create a script to rewrite all requests to - that checks whether the file exists and if it does include it. Or is there another solution? The "File not found" page does respond with a 404 so is there no way to redirect this or show the 404 page?

Comment: If you want to serve existing, static files directly, then those don't need to be rewritten to your script in the first place. You could add a RewriteCond that checks if the request filename with suffix `.php` appended matches an _existing_ file, and only then rewrite that to the script. Then any existing `/i-am-real.txt` would be served as-is, `/foo`would serve `/foo.php`, if that script existed - and `/bar`, with no `/bar.php` actually existing, should then trigger your 404 error document again.

Comment: @CBroe Do you know which RewriteCond would do this? I tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`, which redirects /test to the 404 page, but not /test.php which also doesn't exist.

Comment: @CBroe there is no "routing system" here.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # Remove .php file extension
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

Because you are blindly rewriting the request to append `.php` for any request that does not map to a file (and does not contain a dot). Instead of rewriting the request when the requested file does not exist, you should only rewrite the request when the target file *does* exist.

When you request `/test.html` then this does not match `^([^\.]+)$` (which excludes dots), so the directive does nothing and your `ErrorDocument` is served.

However, when you request `/test` then this is internally rewritten to `/test.php` which then seems to be routed directly to your PHP engine (possibly via a proxy), hence the error "Primary script unknown". Unfortunately, this will likely mean that any non-existent `.php` files will produce the same response - your `.htaccess` file is not even processed for such requests.

You should test first whether the target `.php` exists first before trying to rewrite to it.

For example, assuming your `.htaccess` file is in the document root, try the following instead:

```
# Remove .php file extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Now, only when the target `.php` exists is the request rewritten.

There's no need to backslash-escape literal dots in the regex character class.

*Aside:* Despite your code comment "Remove .php file extension", this rule does the complete opposite, it appends the `.php` extension. It allows URLs to work that doesn't include the `.php` extension.

Comment: I tried this, so when I access /test it shows the 404 page, but if I try to access /test.php it doesn't show the 404 page. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @jxips That would seem to be to do with how PHP is installed on your server. As I mentioned above, your server (or front-end proxy) is likely configured to send all `.php` requests to a backend server that processes the PHP directly. Your `.htaccess` file is probably not even processed for such requests. You'll need to contact your host.